# sqlalchemy: 'metadata.drop_all' does not work

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I tried to drop all the exist tables in the schema by using 'Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)', and recreate a new table. However, the table did not be dropped as I thought, and records were just appended to the old table. I'm new to sqlalchemy, could anyone tell me what I was doing wrong here...thanks!

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:pswd@127.0.0.1:3306/bond?charset=utf8", echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
table = Table('TradeHistory', Base.metadata,
     Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True),
     Column('trade_date', String(50)),
     Column('rem_period', String(50)),
      Column('bond_code', String(50)),
      Column('bond_name', String(50)),
      Column('bond_rating', String(50)),
      Column('bond_yield', String(50)),
      Column('note', String(50)),
      Column('offer', String(50)),
      Column('bid', String(50)),
      Column('amount', String(50)))
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
conn.execute(table.insert(), listToWrite)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)` will drop all tables that it *knows* about.

You are defining table `'TradeHistory'` after that line, so that table is not going to be deleted.

So, first define your whole data model (that is usually done in a separate `model` module btw), then perform operations like `drop_all` and `create_all`.

Comment: re: line 1, "...that it knows about". How would someone test which tables it *knows* about?

Comment: @RolyPoly `Base.metadata.tables.values()` to see which tables it knows about chance is its seeing none if drop_allis not working.